# GET LIKES from a URL

Tags: url, facebook-graph-api, get

Sorry my English is very bad, but I try my best:

We have a URL (eurosmail.de) with 2 Likes:

graph.facebook.com/http://eurosmail.de

Okay , now we get the ID :

https://graph.facebook.com/?domain=www.eurosmail.de

Okay , we have the ID : 10150622492884962

We take this ID to get the Likes:

http://graph.facebook.com/10150622492884962/likes

But the Array is empty , were is the mistake?

Does anyone know a method?